# Simulating the passing of time in unittesting

Tags: python, testing, mocking, integration-testing, celery

I've built a paywalled CMS + invoicing system for a client and I need to get more stringent with my testing.

I keep all my data in a Django ORM and have a bunch of Celery tasks that run at different intervals that makes sure that new invoices and invoice reminders get sent and cuts of access when users don't pay their invoices.

For example I'd like to be a able to run a test that:

1. Creates a new user and generates an invoice for X days of access to the site
2. Simulates the passing of X + 1 days, and runs all the tasks I've got set up in Celery.
3. Checks that a new invoice for an other X days has been issued to the user.

The KISS approach I've come up with so far is to do all the testing on a separate machine and actually manipulate the date/time at the OS-level. So the testing script would:

1. Set the system date to day 1
2. Create a new user and generate the first invoice for X days of access
3. Advance then system date 1 day. Run all my celery tasks. Repeat until X + 1 days have "passed"
4. Check that a new invoice has been issued

It's a bit clunky but I think it might work. Any other ideas on how to get it done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to change the return value of the function you use to get the time (`datetime.datetime.now` for example).

There are various ways to do so (see the mock documentation), but here is one :

```
import unittest
import datetime
from mock import patch

class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.time = datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 18)
        class fakedatetime(datetime.datetime):
            @classmethod
            def now(cls):
                return self.time
        patcher = patch('datetime.datetime', fakedatetime)
        self.addCleanup(patcher.stop)
        patcher.start()

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 18))
        self.time = datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 20)
        self.assertEqual(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 20))
```

Because we can't replace directly `datetime.datetime.now`, we create a fake datetime class that does everything the same way, except returning a constant value when now is called.

Comment: I get an error when trying this:  TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'.   Trace: Traceback (most recent call last): //
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> //
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock.py", line 623, in __enter__ //
    setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot that. I've had that problem recently, and I have a workaround. Just give me a few minutes and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hmm, didn't get the version running as well, sorry.  After calling `setUp()` the results of `datetime.datetime.now()` are not influenced by setting `self.time`.  Maybe I'm getting it wrong still.

Comment: Here is the example with some real code : http://pastebin.com/uppEEihJ . I just tested, the test passes. Do you use celery in your test setup ?

Comment: Got it running now, and it worked.  But it was a little tricky.  I'm just using plain old python 2.7 for testing such things.  In your case the unit test case class lacks a runTest() method, so I cannot create an instance of it without throwing an exception.  What environment is yours that it can handle this situation?
Anyway, if I change your test_something() to runTest(), it works fine.  Thank your for your patience :)

Comment: I'm a little concerned about shadowing the whole module, though.  If I must only shadow one function of a module and must not shadow any other, how can I accomplish this?  Can the Mock instances (or whatever patch() installs) act as proxies to the shadowed entities?

Comment: Python 2.7 using nose to collect the tests, but that shouldn't make a difference.datetime.datetime is a class, not a module, hence the trick to only replace now. patch can replace a module, a class or a method, but not a method of a built in class.

Comment: So if I want to patch the behaviour of `datetime.datetime()` but leave `datetime.foobar()` intact, I cannot do this with mock/patch?  Most unfortunate.

Comment: You can (sorry if I wasn't clear). You can patch anything with mock.patch. But in that specific case, I have to replace the whole `datetime.datetime` class, and not just the `datetime.datetime.now()` method. That's why I create a `fakedatetime` that inherits from `datetime.datetime` to keep all the methods unchanged except `now()`.

Comment: Ah! Was missing that point of inheriting the original.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Are there easy means for shadowing existing instances (instead of classes) as well?

Comment: The same way. `patch` works for everything. You can think of it as a clean way to do `somemodule.something = somemockedthing`. The only case in which it doesn't work is when you can do `stuff = thing` (try `datetime.datetime.x = 42` if you want to see for yourself).

Comment: But that would replace the patched thing without any access to it (at least I don't see how).  I'm asking about the case that there is an existing thing which I need to compute the mock value.  Can mock objects use the objects they replace?  How is this done typically?  Can they somehow relay all calls to the objects they replace (without any knowledge about which calls this will be)?

Answer (score 4):

Without the use of a special mock library, I propose to prepare the code for being in mock-up-mode (probably by a global variable).  In mock-up-mode instead of calling the normal time-function (like time.time() or whatever) you could call a mock-up time-function which returns whatever you need in your special case.

I would vote down for changing the system time.  That does not seem like a unit test but rather like a functional test as it cannot be done in parallel to anything else on that machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at `freezegun` module. Github - https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

From their docs

```
from freezegun import freeze_time
import datetime


@freeze_time("2012-01-14")
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's @madjar's technique as a reusable context manager, and it mocks up the `time` module at the same time in case your stuff uses that rater than `datetime.now()`:

```
import datetime
import time
import mock
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def mock_passage_of_time(
        hours: int = 0,
        minutes: int = 0,
        seconds: int = 0
):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    mock_now = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

    class MockDateTime(datetime.datetime):
        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return mock_now

    with mock.patch('datetime.datetime', MockDateTime), \
         mock.patch('time.time', mock.MagicMock(return_value=mock_now.timestamp())):
        yield
```

Usage:

```
class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        orig_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        five_mins_in_the_future = orig_now + timedelta(minutes=5)

        with mock_passage_of_time(minutes=5):
            delta = datetime.datetime.now() - five_mins_in_the_future
            self.assertEqual(delta.seconds, 0)
```