# Setting time and date in JUnit test fixture

Tags: java, junit

As part of Java code some task needs to be done tomorrow in JUnit.

For example  there are 3 tasks:

- task1 - done
- task2 - do it tomorrow
- task3 - then this will happen

So as per requirement I need to set today's date as tomorrow in Java.

Comment: Can you show us the source of your unit tests?

Comment: i do not need to use any framwork .i only have 3 tasks after each other like three method calls.f1()  - > f2() -> f3(). f2 can be done tomorrow and then in result f3 will be called.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652097/simulating-the-passing-of-time-in-unittesting

Answer (score 11):

The root of your problem is that the system clock (what gives you the time in a `new Date ()`) is not giving you the time you need for your test.

You can avoid this problem by introducing a level of indirection.  Instead of having your code directly ask the Java API what the current time is, you have your code ask a `Clock` object what the time is. In the real program your `Clock` implementation uses the system clock. For your unit tests you use a `FakeClock`, which says whatever time you want it to. You tell your code what `Clock` to use using *dependency injection*. You have to write the `Clock` interface (or abstract base class) and its concrete implementations yourself.

This approach requires you to alter your existing code, so it is easier to test. Or write it in the first place so it is easier to test. It's one of the tricks of unit testing.

I'm working on some code at the moment that is time sensitive. My clock interface is simply

```
 public interface Clock {
    long getCurrentTime ();
 }
```

Comment: Nice, I love this.

Answer (score 7):

The key is to extract the idea of "something which can give you the current time" as a dependency. (Along with the relevant time zone.)

So instead of using `new Date()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` you use a `Clock` abstraction. For production code you inject an instance of this which uses the underlying system clock, but for testing you use a fake clock which you can control explicitly, to make it return whatever you want to.

(It's really not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - but this approach is my standard approach to making time testable.)

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is a replacement for Java's date and time classes. It provides

```
DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(long millis);
```

which can be used in your tests.

Comment: +1. I have been setting up a time limited trial edition and keep seeing Joda Time in SO answers about time. This was the issue which made it worthwhile changing to Joda Time. It took me less than an hour to install it, change my code to use it, and set up my test with this suggestion.

Comment: The call should be `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(...)`. This is the call for setting a specific date time. `DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()` (parameterless) sets DateTime to use the current system time. See http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code on GitHub: [DateSupplier](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/libex/src/main/java/org/libex/concurrent/DateSupplier.java) && [DateController](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/concurrent/DateController.java). `DateSupplier` has a static method that returns the current date. `DateController` allow you to manipulate the date value that is returned by `DateSupplier` in a test environment. It is a `JUnit Rule` and cleans up after itself.

This is a concrete implementation of the `Clock` ideas from the other two answers. I have been using it in my projects for a year or so with good success. Any time I have code that would do `new Date()` I call `DateSupplier.getCurrentDate()` instead.