# JMockit mocking System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

Running this test:

```
@Test
public void testSystemCurrentTimeMillis() {
    new NonStrictExpectations(System.class) {{
        System.currentTimeMillis(); result = 1438357206679L;
    }};
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    assertEquals(1438357206679L, currentTime);
}
```

I get an IllegalStateException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing invocation to mocked type at this point; please make sure such invocations appear only after the declaration of a suitable mock field or parameter
    at unittests.DateTest$1.(DateTest.java:24)
    at unittests.DateTest.testSystemCurrentTimeMillis(DateTest.java:23)
```

What's wrong with my Test (JMockit 1.18)?

Comment: What is result ? can you please share the entire class code. Also what is NonStrictExpectations ??? can you share the code for that too.

Comment: NonStrictExpectations is a JMockit class. result is used for JMockit mocking. http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#expectation

Comment: I always use org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils to get current time DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis() and in unit test DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(longValue) at the end  DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229525/setting-time-and-date-in-junit-test-fixture

Comment: I wanna do it with JMockit.

Comment: Why are you testing the value of System.currentTimeMillis()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so many things with JMockit, it's easy enough to do. Try this..

```
@Test
public void testSystemCurrentTimeMillis(@Mocked final System unused) {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        System.currentTimeMillis(); result = 1438357206679L;
    }};
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    assertEquals(1438357206679L, currentTime);
}
```

Found [this](https://blog.42.nl/articles/mockito-powermock-vs-jmockit/) site to be an excellent reference, by the way. Probably you were tripped up by the static method. All you need to do is declare the class with the static method as mocked--you never need to refer to the variable, hence I named it "unused".

Comment: Accepted your answer, but I only wanted to mock the method currentTimeMillis(), not the whole System class. Seems to be a bug in JMockit.

Comment: @trunkc It's not a bug, but a limitation of the "partial mocking" feature: it cannot handle `native` methods like `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This limitation, however, only applies to the Expectations API; you can mock only the desired `native` method by creating a `MockUp<System>` (which uses the Mockups API).

Comment: You should add a hint about this limitation in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

My final solution is to create a *MockUp* for *System*, that only mocks the method *currentTimeMillis()*:

```
private static class SystemMock extends MockUp<System> {
    @Mock
    public static long currentTimeMillis() {
        return 10000000L;
    }
}

@Test
public void testAddNowDate() {
    new SystemMock();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    assertEquals(10000000L, currentTime);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution in this case. That said, you should try to avoid mocking the system clock whenever possible; the need to mock it in a test hints at a design issue in the code under test.

Comment: @Rogério care to elaborate? How can I test functionality that depends on the system clock without mocking it?

Comment: Code that needs the current time should use a higher-level type (`java.util.Date`, `java.time.LocalDate`, etc.), not `currentTimeMillis()`. And then it should allow for date/time objects to be passed in from client code, rather than always obtaining the current time. Unless, of course, you *really* need the current system clock time in milli/nano-seconds. As I said, calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` is quite possibly a design issue, but I can't know for sure without more information.

Comment: Well one use case is to make a mock-test case for checking elapsed time with currentTimeMillis or even nanoTime.  If you mock it you could check for border cases.  I tried but it was getting too involved in my case.. too many OOM Errors etc.

Comment: Yes! Everything on the internet says there is a design issue when mocking System but that is like saying we should never use System which just isn't true. Sometimes there is a design issue. Sometimes there is nothing you can do to change said design. Sometimes you just need help to mock System regardless of design.

Answer (score 1):

This thing has been introduced in JMockit version 1.17 only to use object reference with your NonStrictExpectation(){} block,Deprecated attribute value for Mocked

> Deprecated the "value" attribute of @Mocked, which is used for "static" partial mocking. Existing uses should be replaced with "dynamic" partial mocking, by passing the instance or class to partially mock in a call to the Expectations(Object...) constructor, or by applying a MockUp class.

Please refer the below link: [JMockit version history](http://jmockit.org/changes.html)

Comment: I don't use the value attribute of @Mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is partial mocking. With small correction in the nonStrictExpectation(){} your above mentioned code can also get fix:

```
@Mocked
private System system;

new NonStrictExpectations() {{
    System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    result = 1438357206679L;
}};

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
assertEquals(1438357206679L, currentTime);
```

This should also work.

Comment: This example is not using partial mocking.

Answer (score 0):

I use PowerMock for this:

```
private void configureSystemClockMock(final int clockJump) {
    AtomicInteger callCount = new AtomicInteger();

    Answer<Integer> answer = invocation -> {
        callCount.addAndGet(1);
        return callCount.get() * clockJump;
    };

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    PowerMockito.doAnswer(answer).when(System.class);
    System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Of course you put whatever you wish in the invocation.